# How to create hyper link in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, dom-events, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in ExtJS 4.I have been getting stuck at a point where I have to create a hyperlink in ExtJS 4.I have been searching a lot for creating hyperlink in ExtJS 4 but I  did not get any solution for it.Actually I have to create a hyperlink and after clicking on that link I am going to display another page in ExtJS 4. Actually also i did not get the event in ExtJS 4. How can I use hyperlink in ExtJS 4.
I am using this way...

```
{
      xtype: 'panel',
      html:'<a href="second.js">Second page</a>',
}
```

Please give me some suggestions.....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd use an `autoEl` for this.

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'a',
        href: 'http://www.example.com/',
        html: 'Example.com'
    }
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/DfbKh/2/)

Comment: thanks for your reply.But I want to display another page in extjs4.Is it possible to display it?

Comment: ExtJS is single page, what do you mean with the next page?

Comment: Actually I want to display another page which is designed in extjs4 in same application.I dont want to move to another web site

Comment: Well isn't it just calling another URL in your application? Image the starting app to be on `localhost/index.html` then your second page would be `localhost/second.html` I think you're making this harder than it is. Do you need to pass variables to the 2nd page?

Comment: It is not required to pass variable to second page.I just want to display another page which is designed in extjs4.Is it possible to do it?and path is not changed "localhost/index.html" it remains same..

Comment: So basically you want to load another ExtJS application on the same page. Check the following url for what you're trying to achieve: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129236-Best-practice-for-multiple-Application-objects-on-one-page However, ExtJS is made for 1 app per page. I recommend you just make another html page or something with your 2nd application and load that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the html property of a label component and call a controller function  from there. Example:

```
{xtype: 'label',
html: 'bla bla? <a href="#" onClick="javascript:appName.app.getController(\'myController\').showRegistration();">Register</a>'
}
```